# Not trivial order by in QueryOver query

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lambda, queryover

Ive got my query built with QueryOver api... now the problem is that I need to sort it by some special value that need to be calculeted in flight...

I've got my products table and I need to sort it by distance from some specific coordinates.. equivalent in SQL will look like `ORDER BY power(abs(p.x - @x),2) + power(abs(p.y - @y),2)`

Now I have no idea how to write it in QueryOver query.. any suggestions?

I will be glad for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using QueryOver this is a bit of a problem, because we need to use Projections when using SQL functions.

I dropped the `abs(...)`, because it is not neccessary, since `x * x == -x * -x`

Option 1: Using a SqlProjection (not pretty, but shorter)

```
int x = 10;
int y = 20;

var result = session.QueryOver<Product>()
    .OrderBy(Projections.SqlProjection(
        @"power(x - " + x.ToString() + ", 2) + power(y - " + y.ToString() + ", 2) as tmporder",
        new string[] { "test" }, 
        new NHibernate.Type.IType[] { NHibernateUtil.Int32 })).Asc
    .List();
```

Option 2: Using SqlFunction - this is longer and requires a look at the link below:

Something like this (you would need to include the OperatorProjection from the link; it's not complete and I didn't test it)

```
.OrderBy(Projections.SqlFunction("power", NHibernateUtil.Double,
    new ArithmeticOperatorProjection("+", NHibernateUtil.Int32,
        Projections.Property<Product>(p => p.x), Projections.Constant(x)),
    Projections.Constant(2))).Asc
```

[NHibernate and the missing OperatorProjection Part 1](http://savale.blogspot.com/2011/04/nhibernate-and-missing.html)

Comment: Sadly I get `Current dialect NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect doesn't support the function: power`.. is there any workaround or I have to make it a *a ?

Comment: @ŁukaszW.pl That is weird. I tested Option 1 with a SQL 2008 database and NH 3.1 and it gave me no error warning. What version of NHibernate are you using?

Comment: Newest possible, but dont worry.. I worked it around.. Thanks for help ;)